# Access SVG node from DOM in React Redux GUI for transforming mouse position to and from viewBox coordinate system

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-redux

I'm rendering some svg using React and using Redux for storing the state of my app.
In order to make sure my mouse input is relative to the svg viewBox I need access to the svg node in the DOM to call getScreenCTM and a bunch of related functions to do the transformations of the mouse position to the viewBox coordinate system and back in the event handlers.

Is it possible to do this in a safe way?

Is it possible to instantiate my own version of whatever class these things live in with the same viewbox that I can pass in to my event handlers?

Is the right way to build my own transformation functions that do the forward and inverse transform so I don't need to bother finding the svg node in the DOM?

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be safe? You can't create a class, but I don't see why you would need to. The right way would be to use the methods SVG provides, much simpler and less error prone than rolling your own.

Comment: Problem is, how do I get hold of the SVG DOM node if it's generated by react?

Comment: Give it an id and use getElementById perhaps? It depends on exactly how you generate it.

Comment: Is it generated using a `use` element? Most (all?) browsers lock the actual SVG content from a `use`'s `href` in a shadow DOM that is completely inaccessible.

Comment: They do so because that's what the SVG specification says they should do. Perhaps <use> is the wrong thing for your requirements. Do make sure you're not using a hammer to knock in the screws.

Comment: I solved it using a ref from the SVG node into a global variable. Not in the spirit of react and redux but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a ref to a global variable solved it.
Solution looks roughly like this:

```
var SVG_REF

...

 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             width="1000"
             height="500"
             ...
             ref={(svg_node) => {
                 if(svg_node != null) {
                     SVG_REF = svg_node
                 }

             }}>
```

After this I can access the SVG_REF when I need to do coordinate system transformations.